# Webpack build refers to absolute paths in local file system

Tags: webpack, build, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I am building add-in for MS Word using office js. They provide you with starter-kits and I have built it using their react-starter. It includes a webpack configuration which I have kept pretty much the same. I added an svg-loader and a copy. It is included below.

My issue is that after I build for production some compiled files in the dist folder are referring to absolute paths on my own local computer file system. What is causing this problem?

[Edit: I created a fresh office js react add-in project to see if I get the same issue. And yes, it is still referring to absolute paths.]

(dist/taskpane.js)

> reactHotLoaderGlobal?reactHotLoaderGlobal.default:void 0;if(e){var n=void 0!==r?r:t;if(n)if("function"!=typeof n){for(var o in n)if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,o)){var i=void 0;try{i=n[o]}catch(e){continue}e.register(i,o,**"/Users/current_user/app_folder/another_app_folder/src/taskpane/components/Collections/index.ts"**)}}else e.register(n,"module.exports",**"/Users/current_user/app_folder/another_app_folder/src/taskpane/components/Collections/index.ts"**)}}()},25522:function(e,t,n){"use strict";var o=this&&this.__createBinding||(Object.create?function(e,t,n,r){void 0===r&&(r=n);var o=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(t,n);o&&!("get"in

(webpack.config.js)

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3002/";
const urlProd = "https://url-to-prod.com/"; 
async function getHttpsOptions() {
  const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
  return { cacert: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert };
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "core-js", "@fluentui/react"],
      taskpane: ["react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/taskpane/index.tsx"],
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
    },
    output: {
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "webpack:///[resource-path]?[loaders]",
      clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "ts-loader"],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader",
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
          generator: {
            filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "svg-url-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "file-loader",
              options: {
                name: "[name].[ext]",
                outputPath: "fonts/",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "src/web.config",
            to: "src/web.config",
          },
        ],
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: "assets/*",
            to: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "assets/icons/*",
            to: "assets/icons/[name][ext][query]",
          },
          {
            from: "manifest*.xml",
            to: "[name]." + buildType + "[ext]",
            transform(content) {
              if (dev) {
                return content;
              } else {
                return content
                  .toString()
                  .replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["taskpane", "vendor", "polyfills"],
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["commands"],
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: ["es6-promise", "Promise"],
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      https: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3002,
    },
  };

  return config;
};
```

Comment: Do you get the same issue with just generated by yeoman add-in files? Or does it happen after you do changes in the config file?

Comment: Yes I do. I tried creating a fresh project and built it directly after generation, and I still get the same issue.

Comment: I think you can file an issue on the [generator-office](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office) repo in that case.

Comment: By "compiled files" maybe you mean map files? That set up debug mapping between compiled files and the source files?

Comment: I do not think I mean map files. This is inside the file "taskpane.js", which I assume is one of the static files that is part of the application on my server. There is another file called "taskpane.js.map" and this has no issues as far as I can see. 

Maybe this is the expected behaviour? Are the files in the dist-folder supposed to refer to files in my local computer? It seems strange to me, and in either way I do not want to put that info up on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the "react-hot-loader/webpack" from the "tsx"-rule it solved the issue. The absolute path was not included in the build anymore.

Comment: I do not fully understand why this rule was included in the webpack. Is it supposed to include the absolute path on my file system? Because it seems strange to me. Or was it just configured in the wrong way?